# Single Sign Out principle in keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, keycloak

I am exploring keycloak for my project SSO solution, and I am trying the open-connect on this blog https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/05/25/easily-secure-your-spring-boot-applications-with-keycloak/

And I would like to as one question about Single Sign Out, I would like to know what’s the principle behind. Tried to search online document but I didn’t find any clue .For a while, I was thinking there is no elegant solution for Single Sign Out in oauth2 world.

Answer (score 10):

This is the way Keycloak implements it (yes, this is not part of OAuth):

- when you use Keycloak to create a server side session in your application using the Java Client, Keycloak will trigger a logout of the session once the logout at Keycloak is triggered. You'll need to set up an Admin URL for your application in Keycloak. This is called "backchannel logout" in the documentation.
- When you use Keycloak in a HTML5 client, Keycloak will create a hidden IFRAME that will check that the Keycloak-Cookie is still present. If it is not, the HTML5 application knows that you have been logged out.

Comment: Is there a detailed document or flow diagram for this Single Sign out?

Comment: there are only multiple references in the server administration and securing apps guide https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/server_admin/ - https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/content/securing_apps/ but not in depth documentation.

Comment: @ahus1 this is only a thing for OpenID Connect clients, SAML clients don't have an Admin URL field

Comment: "backchannel logout" was crucial  & thanks...had trouble logging outta keycloak apps

Answer (score 2):

[OpenID Connect Back-Channel Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html) seems to be the way to go nowadays. It works by exposing a special end-point in your application (`backchannel_logout_uri`), which will be invoked by the OpenID Provider when the user logs out from SSO. Through this endpoint, the Provider gives you a signed Logout Token, to notify your application that the user's session should be terminated.

Because a user may be logged in from multiple devices, browsers, etc., the OpenID Provider can also include a Session ID (`sid` claim) as part of the Logout token. You can compare it with the `sid` that you would have received in the ID Token during login, to decide which session to terminate.

The standard back-channel logout was implemented in Keycloak 12.0, which [shipped in December 2020](https://www.keycloak.org/2020/12/keycloak-1200-released.html). Earlier versions only implemented an alternative, proprietary mechanism.